# "AssertionError: False is not True" When I am trying to run my code

Tags: python

I am getting an error on this function:

```
def test_returns_true_when_feature_is_enabled(self):
    # Arrange
    mock_client = mock.MagicMock()
    mock_client.is_feature_enabled.return_value = True
    with patch.object(fullstack_service, 'get_optly_object', return_value=mock_client):
      with patch('services.js_validator.js_validator_service_rollout._get_account_id', return_value=123):
        # Act / Assert
        self.assertTrue(should_use_js_validator_service())
```

The error I get is:

```
AssertionError: False is not true
test/services_test/js_validator_test/js_validator_service_rollout_test.py:44: AssertionError
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this 100% without knowing what `should_use_js_validator_service()` is returning.

Answer (score 0):

With a liberal use of the Internet, I found that on [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-unittest-asserttrue-function/),  when the first parameter is `False`, `assertTrue`  fails the test and prints the (seemingly optional) second parameter. When the first parameter is `True`, it doesn't do anything. The issue is that the function `should_use_js_validator_service()`, which you have passed to `assertTrue`, does not return a truthy value.